# one of the buttons are working but not the other... and im having trouble using links in php

Tags: php, html, css

I have a drop down menu where you are supposed to choose a site then click a button, and be redirected to the site you chose. im new to php, but i want to learn more. the first button works, but the second one doesnt..
HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="process.php">
<select name="taskOption">
<option value="Select">Please select a site</option>
<option value="Itslearning">Itslearning</option>
<option value="ndla">NDLA</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Take me there"/>
</form>


<form action="process.php">
    <button class="button button1 button1:hover">Take me there</button>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$option = isset($_POST['taskOption']) ? $_POST['taskOption'] : false;
if ($option) {
  echo htmlentities($_POST['taskOption'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
} else {
 echo "Venligst velg en side.";
 exit; 
}
```

The php currently only shows what you have picked, id like it to redirect you to the site you choose.

Comment: What sites? There is some information missing here, like where the urls are / come from. And your second button submits another - empty - form. You would need to include it in the original form or use javascript to submit the first form when you click the second button.

Comment: What the urls are is irrelevant, the second button is stylized with some CSS, and ultimately id like to only have that one. Not too sure how to do that, but thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure about your question. But here are my thoughts:

"`<form>`" submission only works with input type submit. That's why the  first button works. For redirection on a php level, you have to use

```
header("Location: http://urlhere.com");
```

So for your case you might want to have the url of the page as the value like:

```
<option value="http://www.Itslearning.com">Itslearning</option>
```

And in you php:

```
$option = isset($_POST['taskOption']) ? $_POST['taskOption'] : false;
if ($option) {
    header("Location: $option");
}
```

This is untested so do try it out.

Answer (score 0):

In Process.php file use the following code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['taskOption']) && $_POST['taskOption']!="" && $_POST['taskOption']!="Select") {
   header("Location: ".$_POST['taskOption']."");
}
else {
   echo "Venligst velg en side.";
   exit; 
}
?>
```

taskOption must send the sitename, for Eg: mysite.com

Also the second form is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is a FORM with a method and an action how to use the PHP script.

The second one is still a FORM, but... from what I see, it should only access another file/page.
For this you don't need a FORM. you need a simple HTML button.

```
 <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

If anything else is required, please detail.